# How to assign GameObject to a instantiated prefab?

Tags: unity, c#

GameObject A (Panel - CraftSystem) is in the scene already as seen on the screenshot ([Screenshot](http://prnt.sc/drdhi3)). I then instantiate the GameObject B (WorkingStation) which has a public GameObject craftSystem. So I need to assign A to B after B is instantiated.

this is the instantiated object code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class WorkingStation : MonoBehaviour
 {

     public KeyCode openInventory;
     public GameObject craftSystem;    //Game Object that needs to be assigned from hierarchy
     public int distanceToOpenWorkingStation = 3;
     bool showCraftSystem;
     Inventory craftInventory;
     CraftSystem cS;


     // Use this for initialization
     void Start()
     {
         if (craftSystem != null)
         {
             craftInventory = craftSystem.GetComponent<Inventory>();
             cS = craftSystem.GetComponent<CraftSystem>();
         }
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         float distance = Vector3.Distance(this.gameObject.transform.position, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position);

         if (Input.GetKeyDown(openInventory) && distance <= distanceToOpenWorkingStation)
         {
             showCraftSystem = !showCraftSystem;
             if (showCraftSystem)
             {
                 craftInventory.openInventory();
             }
             else
             {
                 cS.backToInventory();
                 craftInventory.closeInventory();
             }
         }
         if (showCraftSystem && distance > distanceToOpenWorkingStation)
         {
             cS.backToInventory();
             craftInventory.closeInventory();
         }
     }
 }
```

this is the code used to instantiate it:

```
 public void SetItem(GameObject b)
 {
     hasPlaced = false;
     currentBuilding = Instantiate(b).transform;
     placeableBuilding = currentBuilding.GetComponent<PlaceableBuilding>();
 }
```

Ive tried to do `craftSystem = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CraftSystem");` but it does not work as after i instantiate the object B the public GameObject stays empty and i get null reference error to this line "craftInventory.openInventory();"

Ive also tried `craftSystem = GameObject.Find("Panel - CraftSystem(Clone)");` and get the same result. public GameObject craftSystem still stays empty and i get null reference error.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is here. I *guess* you want to assign some `public GameObject` variable in your `class PlaceableBuilding`? Then it would be as trivial: `placeableBuilding.variable = someGameObject`. But maybe you wonder how to get the game object? In order to answer that question we would need to know more about your object hierarchy.

Comment: The WorkingStation script has public GameObject and I want to assing an Object from hierarchy to it.

Comment: Is the method `SetItem` in a class which has a reference to the game object which contains the craft system (or maybe it's even in that class)? And what do you mean with "from hierarchy"? From *where* in your hierarchy?

Comment: SetItem is only used to instantiate the GameObject (a building) which is set in inspector. What i need to somehow assign is public GameObject craftSystem; From hierarchy i mean http://prnt.sc/drdhi3

Comment: @Barbas I've edited my answer, please take a look.

Comment: `if (craftSystem != null)` ... I think you mean `if (craftSystem == null)` ("when you don't know where the craft system is, go find it").

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to assign a GameObject (a prefab, let's call it **A** ) to another prefab, which you just instantiated (let's call it **B**).

There are 2 ways to do that :

1. IF, the Prefab **A** is present in your game's hierarchy, then you can get it's reference using [GameObject.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) or [GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html), and then assign it to your GameObject variable (*craftSystem*, in your case).

After Looking at the screenshot, I see that the Prefab **A** is instantiated at run-time and is not present in hierarchy at compile time (hence suffix *clone*).

Add the following line inside Start function, before anything else

craftSystem = GameObject.Find("Panel - CraftSystem(Clone)");

2. IF, the Prefab **A** isn't present in the hierarchy, then you need to put that Prefab inside a folder called **Resources**, then call [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), on the saved Prefab (**A**), with this you'll get a reference to that prefab, which you can then assign to your *craftSystem* variable.

P.S. If this is not what you're looking for, then you need to make your question more clear, and i'll update my answer according to that.

Comment: Yes the GameObject A (Panel - CraftSystem) is in the scene already as seen on the screenshot. I then instantiate the GameObject B (WorkingStation) which has a public GameObject craftSystem. So I need to assign A to B after B is instantiated.

Comment: Then you should try to use GameObject.Find or GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag as I've said in my first point.

Comment: Sorry If i misread or anything, but I don't see any screenshot attached to the question.

Comment: it was attached to one of the comments: prnt.sc/drdhi3 I have tried using GameObject.Find and findwithtag but it doesnt seem to be working.  craftSystem = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CraftSystem"); Unless this is totally wrong

Comment: You need to have a tag on your CraftSystem - panel gameObject, only then the above method will work. Select CraftSystem Gameobject in the Hierarchy and in the Inspector window assign a Tag to it.

Comment: it does have the tag CraftSystem

Comment: Please update your question with the suggested edit/answers, so we can see everything in one place. And, also include the information about what result are you getting. Because, comments are not for extended discussion it seems.